# How to mute video in aframe.js?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am using

```
<a--assets>
 <video id="penguin-sledding" autoplay  loop="true" src="v.mp4"> 
</a-assets>
```

assets,Now how can i mute this video by code

```
<a-video src="#penguin-sledding" width="16" height="9" position="0 0 -20"></a-video>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some html5 video controls, though not all will work. Luckily "muted" easily does the trick. Also, you have an extra hyphen in `<a-assets>` you need to remove. The following code will play a muted video.

```
<a-assets>
    <video muted id="penguin-sledding" autoplay  loop="true" src="v.mp4"> 
</a-assets>

<a-video src="#penguin-sledding" width="16" height="9" position="0 0 -20"></a-video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to change it by code:

```
$("video").prop('muted', true);
```